# How do I cancel an ajax call made using sajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, refactoring, sajax

a long while back when I built my first web application I used sajax by modernmethod to add ajax features to it. NOw its been a while and I have to clean it up a bit - I haven't set any real checks and my code of the time is terrible inefficient and to top things off it seems that sajax is dead?

How do you cancel a specific ajax request made using sajax? please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest object has an [abort](http://javascript.about.com/library/blajax11.htm) function but i don't know how stuff works with sajax.

Comment: I checked the library and it seems that sajax puts all XMLHTTPREquest objects into an array queue.

Comment: So you may itarate over the array and abort them?

Comment: Done - required a bit of hacking here - set it up so it returned the index of the array where the function was and I maintained the index position in a global. Easy to abort a selected index in the queue now that I know which index refers to which  request. Thanks for the idea!